# How does MyJio app draw over apps when I've disabled that in the app settings?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, permissions, motorola-moto-g

The MyJio (com.jio.myjio) android is able to draw over other apps in my Moto G5+ running Android 7.0.

I have disabled the 'Draw over apps' feature by going to Settings > Apps > Gear icon > Special access > Draw over other apps > MyJio.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

Comment: The second screenshot looks like from being within the app itself (the "rounded head" shining through). If that's so, it is not "drawing over *other* apps", but just on itself.

Comment: @Izzy No. It's not. This thing pops up randomly on my phone.